# Can't set primary key in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008

I created a table in SQL Server Management Studio. I right-clicked the column I want it to be primary key. But I can't set it. It's disabled.

Comment: Ohh Thanks. I'm not a native english. English is not my mother tongue. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 26):

If you are trying to use a varchar or nvarchar field as primary key, you have to specify a length, and not use MAX.

Comment: For anyone who is wondering, the maximum you can specify explicitly is 8,000 for varchar or 4,000 for nvarchar.

Answer (score 5):

Is the column nullable, if so, you need to make it non-nullable

Comment: And of course you can't do that if you currently have some null values, so you have to fix those first if that is the case.

Answer (score 5):

Primary Key column(s) must be unique and non-nullable

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933092%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Try to add the PK constraint by running SQL Query and see if it gives any errors.

```
ALTER TABLE Customer ADD PRIMARY KEY (CustomerId);
```